# Centering an entire table in its outer div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div:

```
<div id="tableContainer">
</div>
```

and I'm dynamically adding a table to this with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var data = '[{"gameid":"1","gamename":"Halo","gamedescription":"Game about aliens","gamegenre":"FPS"},{"gameid":"2","gamename":"Halo 2","gamedescription":"Game about aliens 2","gamegenre":"FPS"}]';

    var json = $.parseJSON(data);

    $("#tableContainer").append("<table>");
    $("#tableContainer").append("<tr>");
    $("#tableContainer").append("<td>Game ID</td>");
    $("#tableContainer").append("<td>Game Name</td>");
    $("#tableContainer").append("<td>Game Description</td>");
    $("#tableContainer").append("<td>Game Genre</td>");
    $("#tableContainer").append("</tr>");
    $.each(json, function (index, value) {
        $("#tableContainer").append("<tr>");
        console.log(value.gameid);
        $("#tableContainer").append("<td>" + value.gameid + "</td>");
        $("#tableContainer").append("<td>" + value.gamename + "</td>");
        $("#tableContainer").append("<td>" + value.gamedescription + "</td>");
        $("#tableContainer").append("<td>" + value.gamegenre + "</td>");
        $("#tableContainer").append("</tr>");
    });
    $("#tableContainer").append("</table>");
});
```

and I want to horizontally center this **entire** table. I'm trying to use

```
#tableContainer {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
#table {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

but having no success. Any ideas? Here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/bn52jk8k/11/

Thanks

Comment: All the table rows and columns are not append into table

Comment: I concur. "<td>" get's appended to "<tr>", "<tr>" get's appended to "<table>" and "<table>" gets appended to the tableContainer. First get the structure right and then trouble shoot formatting.

Comment: If you view source your code after it is been appended the <table> tag is not closed. It is closed outside the <tr> <td> formations.

Comment: Why are you using `#table` in CSS in place of `table`? you dont have an element with `id = table`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify code like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var data = '[{"gameid":"1","gamename":"Halo","gamedescription":"Game about aliens","gamegenre":"FPS"},{"gameid":"2","gamename":"Halo 2","gamedescription":"Game about aliens 2","gamegenre":"FPS"}]';

    var json = $.parseJSON(data);

    var table="<table>"
    +   "<tr>"
    +   "<td>Game ID</td>"
    +   "<td>Game Name</td>"
    +   "<td>Game Description</td>"
    +   "<td>Game Genre</td>"
    +   "</tr>";

    $.each(json, function (index, value) {
      table+="<tr>"
        +   "<td>" + value.gameid + "</td>"
        +   "<td>" + value.gamename + "</td>"
        +   "<td>" + value.gamedescription + "</td>"
        +   "<td>" + value.gamegenre + "</td>"
        +   "</tr>";
    });
    table+="</table>";

    $("#tableContainer").append(table);
});
```

and in CSS,

```
#tableContainer table {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Here is the fiddle;
[Jsfiddle Center align](http://jsfiddle.net/48asqp01/1/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, I was so focused on the CSS not working and didn't realize it could have been my HTML